# Multiplying matrix along one specific dimension

Tags: arrays, matlab, vectorization, matrix-multiplication

**QUESTION**

I'm looking for an elegant way to multiply two arrays along one particular dimension.

**SIMILAR QUESTION**

There is already a [similar question](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/60934) on the official matlab forum, but the thread is outdated (2004).

**EXAMPLE**

`M1` a [6x4x4] matrix and `M2` a [6x1] matrix, I would like to multiply (element by element) `M1` with `M2` along the 3rd dimension of M1 to obtain a matrix M [6x4x4]

An equivalent to:

```
M1 = rand(6,4,4);
M2 = rand(6,1);

for ii = 1:size(M1,2)
   for jj = 1:size(M1,3)
      M(:,ii,jj) = M1(:,ii,jj).*M2;
   end
end
```

**VISUAL EXAMPLE**

[image: multiplication along one particular dimension]

Do you know a cool way to do that ? (no loop, 1 or 2 lines solution,...)

Comment: Your code gives an error: "matrix dimensions must agree" with the indicated sizes. Also, what's the size of the desired result? Maybe try `M = bsxfun(@times, M1, permute(M2, [2 3 1]));`, which gives `M` the same size of `M1`

Comment: For your code to work, you technically need to use `squeeze` on `M1(ii,jj,:)` in order to remove all singleton dimensions and get the corresponding column vector.

Comment: @LuisMendo Doing `M1(ii,jj,:)` would give you a `1 x 1 x n` vector and element-wise multiplying with `M2` gives incompatible dimensions. `squeeze` is required here.

Comment: Indeed my code was wrong, now it's ok.

Comment: You didn't want to use the `repmat` approach?

Answer (score 4):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, you want to take each temporal slice (i.e. `1 x 1 x n`) at each spatial location in `M1` and element-wise multiply it with a vector `M2` of size `n x 1`.  `bsxfun` and `permute` are perfect for that situation:

```
M = bsxfun(@times, M1, permute(M2, [2 3 1]));
```

Comment: That was my interpretation too

Comment: And that was exactly my question :), so there is no way to avoid using bsxfun or a for loop ?

Comment: @obchardon I don't see any way how.... but MATLAB R2016b supports implicit broadcasting, so `bsxfun` is no longer required.

Comment: @rayryeng link to Matlab 2016b broadcasting info?

Comment: @AhmedFasih Currently available in pre-release R2016b. Documentation: http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/relnotes_pr.pdf - Consult page 1-3 (or page 8), at the bottom of the page (re: Implicit Expansion).